# Nested if and IF (And statement on Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, nested, nested-if

I have a spread sheet in which I want to display some data

`Budget 9792.88` --this is b16

`Actual cost 10075.75` --this is b17

I want to create a formula in which if our actual cost is 15% over the budget or larger is displays over budgeted. If it is 15% under budget or larger it displays under budget. And if it is in between those two it displays you stayed within your budget.

I have a working formula but I am getting a value error.

```
=IF(B17<=(B16*1.15),"Met our 15% goal",IF(B17>=(B16/1.15),"Over the budget")),IF(AND(B17<=(B16*1.15),B17>=(B16/1.15)),"Met your goal")
```

Comment: "I have a working formula but I am getting a value error." I don't think that "working formula" means what you think it means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel actually reads the if function from the left like we read a book from left, so there is no need to give in between explanation to if function. Once you assign a value to a position, it will not change by its consecutive value.

```
=IF(A2<A1*0.85,"Under Budget",IF(A2<A1*1.15,"between budget","above budget"))
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
=IF(B17/B16 >= 1.15, "Over budget",IF(B17/B16<=0.85, "Under budget","Met your goal"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you like it to be a little fancy, perhaps?

`=INDEX({"under","within","over"},MATCH(B17/B16,{0,0.85,1.15001},1)) & " budget"`

NB. The `1.150001` in the array ensures that exactly 15% overrun is still considered "within budget", as is exactly 0.85.

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
=IF(B17>=B16*1.15,"Over the budget",IF(B17<=B16*0.85,"Under the budget","Met your goal"))
```